# DataGridView delay in updating DataSource

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datasource, updating

I've a `DataGridView` filled and tied to a SQL Server table.

When I edit a cell in the grid I use the `CellEndEdit` event to update my DataSource (SQL table), but the update doesn't show up until I click on another record, edit it, and leave it.

How can I get the update to happen upon editing the first record?

Here is the code I'm using.

```
Private Sub ParamTable_formtestingDataGridView_CellEndEdit(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles 
  ParamTable_formtestingDataGridView.CellEndEdit
    ParamTable_formtestingDataGridView.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.CurrentCellChange)
    Me.ParamTable_formtestingTableAdapter.Update(Me.PIMUserDBDataSet.ParamTable_formtesting)
End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you need to update the DB cell by cell by cell?  You dont even have to do it a row at a time - you can accumulate a number of changes and apply them all at once

Comment: I'm new to the dataviewgrid.  Can you show me how to do what your suggesting.